# How to listen for fullscreen click event

Tags: javascript, electron

New to Electron.  Working on a [menubar app](https://github.com/maxogden/menubar).   I have things tracking my mouse position even when the menubar item is closed, but I'd also like to listen for a `click` event anywhere on my screen.  How can I do this?

```
const electron = require('electron')
var menubar = require('menubar');

var mb = menubar()

function myCallback() {
  var mouse = electron.screen.getCursorScreenPoint()
  console.log("Mouse is at x:" + mouse.x + " y:" + mouse.y);
}

mb.on('ready', function ready () {
  console.log('app is ready')
  var intervalID = setInterval(myCallback, 100);


  //this doesn't work right now
  electron.screen.addEventListener("click", console.log('clicked'));     
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work,

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', fn, true);
```

Comment: No dice.  Get `document is undefined`

Comment: In case you haven't fixed this problem 5 years later. You probably need to run this function only on the browser not on Node. If you're using react put it in a useEffect hook.